# How to import GoogleSignInClient for play game services version 11.8.0

Tags: google-signin, google-play-games

I am trying to follow the tutorial given [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin) to sign in.

I have configured the **`build.gradle`** file according to the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and using version 11.8.0. I've included the statement

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.8.0'
```

However, I can only import **`GoogleSignInAccount`** and **`GoogleSignInOptions`** classes.

I cannot import the **`GoogleSignInClient`** class though all these classes belong to the same `auth.api.signin` package. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for an example. Checkout the [android-basic-samples/SkeletonTbmp](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/SkeletonTbmp/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tbmpskeleton/SkeletonActivity.java) how GoogleSignInClient is used.

```
//imported
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;

// Client used to sign in with Google APIs
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = null;

// Create the Google API Client with access to Games
// Create the client used to sign in.
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);

/**
 * Start a sign in activity.  To properly handle the result, call tryHandleSignInResult from
 * your Activity's onActivityResult function
 */
public void startSignInIntent() {
  startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

You can check more of these samples in [android-basic-samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following line in your `build.gradle`file :

```
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
```

(check here for the last version you need to use : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup )

Answer (score 0):

Got that same error. I figured out that you have two options to get rid of it.
1. Do all of the android/google specific code in the android package or
2. include the android related includings in the build.gradle under core or desktop etc.

Hope that helps!